# React and node app in firebase not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, deployment

I have a React App with Node(Express) as the backend. React is requesting for an end point /api/users and Node is serving with a static response. This is working fine in local.

The same app has been deployed in firebase and the React part is not able to consume the Node /api/user part, api call failing.

Below is the project structure -

[image]

- The node part is in server.js
- Package.json has the proxy part directing to the Node Port
- The scripts part in package.json is as given below -

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject",
      "server": "nodemon server.js",
      "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"react-scripts start\""
  },
  ```

Not sure what is missing? Just to reiterate that this is working in my local, but not working after deploying to firebase

Comment: What are you seeing that is failing in your call?

Comment: Also you can check the firebase log under functions.

Comment: The call is returning a bunch of html which is irrelevant. It should have given a simple json response. I tried hitting some random end point which does not exist, still the response is the same bunch of html

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. It works fine locally but it does not run the node proxy on firebase hosting. I tried making the "start" script do what the server script does do, but that did not work either.